# Migrate columns to JSON in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table (Table A) that looks like this:

```
Id (int)  
Quantity (int)   
Clicks (int?)  
Opens (int?)  
VendorName (string)
```

I want to convert it to a table (Table B) like this

```
Id (int)  
JsonData (Json that has the 4 fields above)
```

How do you insert/transform into a json column? Or do I just have to construct the json string myself?

Additionally, does the nullableness of the `int` columns affect creation? Are `clicks` for example not included or do they do something like this `{"clicks": null }`?

I read through [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) about JSON, but I didn't see any reference to inserting from SQL columns. Only from other JSON data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server 2016+ you may try a combination of `FOR JSON PATH` with `WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER` and `INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES`.

Starting from SQL Server 2022, you may use `JSON_OBJECT()` function.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
   Id int,  
   Quantity int,   
   Clicks int,  
   Opens int,  
   VendorName varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO TableA (Id, Quantity, Clicks, Opens, VendorName)
VALUES
   (1, 100, 100, 100, 'Vendor1'),
   (2, 200, NULL, 200, 'Vendor2')
```

Statement for SQL Server 2016+:

```
SELECT
   Id,
   (
   SELECT Quantity, Clicks, Opens, VendorName 
   FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
   ) AS JsonData
-- INTO TableB
FROM TableA
```

Statement for SQL Server 2022+:

```
SELECT
   Id,
   JSON_OBJECT(
     'Quantity': Quantity, 
     'Clicks': Clicks, 
     'Opens': Opens, 
     'VendorName': VendorName
     NULL ON NULL
   ) AS JsonData
FROM TableA
```

Result:

```
Id  JsonData
1   {"Quantity":100,"Clicks":100,"Opens":100,"VendorName":"Vendor1"}
2   {"Quantity":200,"Clicks":null,"Opens":200,"VendorName":"Vendor2"}
```

Comment: This is a better solution.  Nice

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
drop table if exists #TableB;
create table #TableB(
  Id            int unique not null,
  JsonData      nvarchar(max) not null);
go

insert #TableB(Id, JsonData) 
select t.Id, (select ta.Quantity, ta.Clicks, ta.Opens, ta.VendorName
              from #TableA ta
              where t.Id=ta.Id
              for json path, root('JsonArray')) 
from #TableA t
group by t.Id;

select tb.Id, oj.Quantity, oj.clicks, oj.Opens, oj.VendorName
from #TableB tb
     cross apply openjson(tb.JsonData, '$.JsonArray') with (Quantity       int,
                                                            Clicks         int,
                                                            Opens          int,
                                                            VendorName     varchar(200)) oj;
```

Comment: how can you make it not an array?

Right now it would come back like `[{"Clicks":11,"TotalViews":11403}]` but since its for sure one to one, we would want `{"Clicks":11,"TotalViews":11403}`

Comment: got it from [JSON PATH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) .

You need to have `for json path, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`